# Optimize MySQL Subquery

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery

I'm rather new to MySQL and am trying to simplify this statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.user_id, a.artist_id, a.artist_name, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM plays WHERE user_id = p.user_id AND artist_id = a.artist_id) as count
FROM plays as p
LEFT OUTER JOIN artists AS a
ON p.artist_id = a.artist_id;
```

This accomplishes what I need but *painfully* slowly. There simply must be some way to do this in a more efficient manner. To give you an idea of the schema:

**artists**

```
artist_id   artist_name
1           ArtistA
2           ArtistB
3           ArtistC
4           ArtistD
```

**plays**

```
user_id     artist_id 
1           1
1           2
1           2
2           4
2           4
3           3
```

And I'm trying to make a table like this:

**plays per artist by user**

```
user_id    artist_id    artist_name    count
1          1            ArtistA        1
1          2            ArtistB        2
2          4            ArtistD        2
4          3            ArtistC        1
```

Granted, I'm working with several hundred thousands rows of data. I wasn't able to find anything on SO pertaining to this certain case but any resources/instruction would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is called a simple aggregation:

```
SELECT p.user_id, a.artist_id, a.artist_name, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM artists a JOIN
     plays p
     ON p.artist_id = a.artist_id
GROUP BY p.user_id, a.artist_id, a.artist_name;
```

Because your aggregation has fields from both tables, it seems that you really want a match between the two tables.  I changed the `LEFT JOIN` to an inner join.

Comment: I've been unable to turn up clear-cut information on `GROUP BY` for multiple columns, and don't had a great conception of exactly what it's doing. In this case, it's grouping rows where `p.user_id`, `a.artist_id`, and `a.artist_name`; are the same, correct?

Comment: @AlexOlsen . . . Yes, that is correct.  Adding columns to `group by` has a small effect the performance.  But, to a large extent the performance issue is the presence of `group by`, not the number (or length) of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Are there indexes on any of your tables? You'll probably want an index on `artist_id` on your `plays` table, if you don't already.

Also, I assume that `artist_id` on `artists` if a primary key, but if not, you'll want to do that too.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html for details.

It might help to provide the output of `DESC SELECT DISTINCT p.user_id, a.artist_id, a.artist_name, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM plays WHERE user_id = p.user_id AND artist_id = a.artist_id) as count
FROM plays as p
LEFT OUTER JOIN artists AS a
ON p.artist_id = a.artist_id;` to check whether your query is using indexes or not.

Having said that, you should switch to gordon-linoff@'s query too.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @thatdamncat! I omitted a couple columns from the plays table (`track_name`, `created_at`) from the demonstration because they're, for the moment, irrelevant. The purpose of this db is for me to experiment with recommender systems, so I'm considering using `track_name` in place of `artist_id` for the query. Not sure which will provide more better matches between users but regardless, will experiment with an index!